# Could not create type 'WorldwideWebServices.TSSecure'

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, exception

I've inherited a legacy web service which builds and runs just fine on a colleague's machine, yet on mine I receive the error:

> Could not create type 'WorldwideWebServices.TSSecure'.

I've been googling and staring at this for hours with no luck, can somebody give me a clue where I should be looking?

Comment: What is the `inner exception` text? Otherwise it sounds like "I can't buy coke". Who, where, when and why?

Comment: It simply fails to build with the aforementioned error, so there is no inner exception. 

Double-clicking on the error take me to the TSSecure.asmx markup which contains:
<%@ WebService Language="c#" Codebehind="TSSecure.asmx.cs" Class="WorldcareWebServices.TSSecure" Debug="true" %>

I added the Debug tag, but to no avail.

Comment: And what of the code-behind where this class lives?

Comment: There's a considerable amount of code-behind. The namespace is 'WorldwideWebServices', and precisely 1200 lines of code that I probably shouldn't be pasting here. Lot's of Oracle calls. Apologies for the broad nature of the question, I realise I am grasping at straws by asking here.

Comment: There are also two usings at the top of the code-behind linking to two other projects in the solution, both of which exist. I did a Get Latest from TFS at the root level, and also did a Get Specific with the two check boxes ticked just to make sure. No luck. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Removing the usings at the top of the code-behind has no effect, nor does renaming the namespace. Same error as above.

Comment: If I exclude the .asmx and .asmx.cs files, it builds.

Comment: So this is a ASMX ASP.NET web service, not a WCF web service, correct?

Comment: Why does the .asmx have "World **care** WebServices.TSSecure", when the class is "World **wide** WebServices.TSSecure"?

Comment: I changed to names manually after editing and used different wording. Abatishchev, it is an asmx asp.net web service. I am not familiar with these.